# twig round function not rounding numbers

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I have the following code:

```
 `{{ app.user.getShop().getClickBalance()/4|round(1, 'ceil') }}
```

Get click balance is the following:

```
/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getClickBalance()
{
    return $this->clickBalance;
}
```

I wonder why this is not rounding up the balance, although I already specify to round up.

So the number when divided by 4 is 437.5 and I want it to show 438

Comment: What do you think the first parameter passed to `round` means?

Comment: rounds either up or down (rounds the value up to precision decimal places away from zero, when it is half way there -- making 1.5 into 2 and -1.5 into -2);

Comment: i tried setting it to 0 but still it shows comma behind it

Comment: I don't believe that https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/5fdbd991bfcf5ea2492c9ab074a2d2cde1878383/test/Twig/Tests/Fixtures/filters/round.test

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this:

`{{ app.user.getShop().getClickBalance()/4|round(0, 'floor') }}`

The first argument is to how many decimals it gets rounded (you want 0) and the second argument is how the number is rounded.

`floor` meaning everything below `.5` is rounded down while `ceil` meaning it is always rounded up.